# Module doctest does not run

Tags: python, doctest

I am trying to use the `doctest` module to test code. I tried this example:

```
import doctest 

def areaTriangulo(base, altura):
    return 'El area del triangulo es: '+str((base*altura)/2)
    """
    funcion que nos devuelve el area de un triangulo
    >>> areaTriangulo(4,5)
    'El area del triangulo es: 20.0'
    """

doctest.testmod()
```

The test has a wrong answer on purpose, but the test tells me that there are no mistakes. Why?

Comment: I tried really hard to find a duplicate for this question, but apparently nobody else has ever put the docstring in the wrong place like this before. I guess it's hard to **find out that there is such a thing** as a docstring, without being told immediately how to do it. Anyway, I guess this should be counted as a typo, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the docstring is at the *top* of the function definition; not at the bottom; otherwise Python won't recognise it as a docstring:

```
def areaTriangulo(base, altura):
    """
        
    funcion que nos devuelve el area de un triangulo
    
    >>> areaTriangulo(4,5)
    'El area del triangulo es: 20.0'
        
    """
    
    return 'El area del triangulo es: '+str((base*altura)/2)
```